# what is the best way to join two tables and use sum function

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to know, what is the best way to achieve the below output in an acceptable/standard way.

I'm trying to join two table results table1 org (primary & foreign key in same table) and table 2 license where I use sum function on it.

Input to the query will be parent_org_id and product the query should get me back parent/child org and license count for each of them.

I was facing problem while combining the results with the functions and where conditions.
I've tried the query provided below. I know it is not up to standard.

- I have used `or` condition to get around both parent and child record.
- also i guess my query performs scan on both table so thinking could that be avoided as both are heavy tables.

Data Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE LICENSE (LICENSE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   ORG_ID NUMBER,  QUANTITY NUMBER,    PRODUCT VARCHAR(10), START_DATE TIMESTAMP(6),   END_DATE TIMESTAMP(6));
Insert into LICENSE (LICENSE_ID,ORG_ID,QUANTITY,PRODUCT,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (1,222,10,'MOVIES', to_timestamp('01-JAN-18 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('04-JAN-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into LICENSE (LICENSE_ID,ORG_ID,QUANTITY,PRODUCT,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (2,222,3,'BOOKS',to_timestamp('01-JUN-18 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('18-DEC-18 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into LICENSE (LICENSE_ID,ORG_ID,QUANTITY,PRODUCT,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (3,222,6,'GOOGLE',to_timestamp('01-JAN-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('31-DEC-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into LICENSE (LICENSE_ID,ORG_ID,QUANTITY,PRODUCT,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (4,222,5, null, to_timestamp('01-JAN-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('31-DEC-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into LICENSE (LICENSE_ID,ORG_ID,QUANTITY,PRODUCT,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (5,222,8, null, to_timestamp('01-JAN-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('31-JAN-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into LICENSE (LICENSE_ID,ORG_ID,QUANTITY,PRODUCT,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (6,222,7,'BOOKS',to_timestamp('01-JAN-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('15-FEB-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));
Insert into LICENSE (LICENSE_ID,ORG_ID,QUANTITY,PRODUCT,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (7,222,7,'MOVIES',to_timestamp('01-JAN-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),to_timestamp('15-FEB-19 00:00:00.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SSXFF'));

CREATE TABLE ORG (ORG_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ORG_NAME VARCHAR2(10), PARENT_ORG_ID NUMBER, FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ORG_ID) REFERENCES ORG(ORG_ID));
Insert into ORG (ORG_ID,ORG_NAME,PARENT_ORG_ID) values (111,'district-1',null);
Insert into ORG (ORG_ID,ORG_NAME,PARENT_ORG_ID) values (999,'district-2',null);
Insert into ORG (ORG_ID,ORG_NAME,PARENT_ORG_ID) values (222,'school-1',111);
Insert into ORG (ORG_ID,ORG_NAME,PARENT_ORG_ID) values (333,'school-2',111);
Insert into ORG (ORG_ID,ORG_NAME,PARENT_ORG_ID) values (444,'school-3',999);
```

Query:

```
select 
o1.org_id as orgId,
o1.org_name as orgName,
sum(nvl(quantity,0)) as totalLicense,
sum(case when END_DATE > systimestamp then quantity  else 0 end) as totalActiveLicense,
sum(case when END_DATE < systimestamp then quantity  else 0 end) as totalExpiredLicense,
sum(case when END_DATE > systimestamp-15 and END_DATE < systimestamp then quantity  else 0 end) as expiredInLast15Days,
sum(case when END_DATE > systimestamp-30 and END_DATE < systimestamp then quantity  else 0 end) as expiredInLast30Days,
sum(case when END_DATE > systimestamp-60 and END_DATE < systimestamp then quantity  else 0 end) as expiredInLast60Days,
sum(case when END_DATE < systimestamp+15 and END_DATE > systimestamp then quantity  else 0 end) as expiringInNext15Days,
sum(case when END_DATE < systimestamp+30 and END_DATE > systimestamp then quantity  else 0 end) as expiringInNext30Days,
sum(case when END_DATE < systimestamp+60 and END_DATE > systimestamp then quantity  else 0 end) as expiringInNext60Days
from org o1 left outer join (
select l.* from org o left outer join license l on o.org_id = l.org_id
where o.parent_org_id=111 or o.org_id=111
AND l.PRODUCT ='GOOGLE') license_info on o1.ORG_ID = license_info.org_id
where o1.parent_org_id=111 or o1.org_id=111
group by o1.org_id, o1.org_name;
```

The query should get me back parent/child org and license count for each of them.

Trying to avoid multiple selects.

Table structure and expected output below.

License Table-1

[image: License Table data]

Org Table-2

[image: Org Table data]

Output

[image: Output]

Any help on this would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from the parent.
Then link the licenses to the parent and the childs of the parent.

```
SELECT 
org1.org_id AS orgId,
org1.org_name AS orgName,
lic.product,
COALESCE(SUM(lic.quantity), 0) AS totalLicense,
SUM(CASE WHEN lic.END_DATE > systimestamp THEN lic.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS totalActiveLicense,
SUM(CASE WHEN lic.END_DATE < systimestamp THEN lic.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS totalExpiredLicense,
SUM(CASE WHEN lic.END_DATE > systimestamp-15 AND lic.END_DATE < systimestamp THEN lic.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS expiredInLast15Days,
SUM(CASE WHEN lic.END_DATE > systimestamp-30 AND lic.END_DATE < systimestamp THEN lic.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS expiredInLast30Days,
SUM(CASE WHEN lic.END_DATE > systimestamp-60 AND lic.END_DATE < systimestamp THEN lic.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS expiredInLast60Days,
SUM(CASE WHEN lic.END_DATE > systimestamp AND lic.END_DATE < systimestamp+15 THEN lic.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS expiringInNext15Days,
SUM(CASE WHEN lic.END_DATE > systimestamp AND lic.END_DATE < systimestamp+30 THEN lic.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS expiringInNext30Days,
SUM(CASE WHEN lic.END_DATE > systimestamp AND lic.END_DATE < systimestamp+60 THEN lic.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS expiringInNext60Days
FROM org org1 
JOIN org org2 ON (org2.org_id = org1.org_id OR org2.parent_org_id = org1.org_id)
LEFT JOIN license lic 
  ON lic.org_id = org2.org_id 
 AND lic.product IN ('GOOGLE')
WHERE org1.org_name = 'district-1'
GROUP BY org1.org_id, org1.org_name, lic.product
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response @LukStorms

  When i use your query it gets me everything for all the product. 
  If i pass a where condition to get for a specific product.  I get the results only for those orgs who contains that product. 

  I'd like to get the orgs (parent & child) irrespective of that product is available to those orgs.

Comment: @Naveen Ah, I assume that's the effect you get when you add a criteria in the WHERE clause for a left joined table. Which would filter out the unmatched, thus having the same effect as an INNER JOIN.  You can fix that by putting the criteria in the LEFT JOIN: `LEFT JOIN license lic ON (lic.org_id = org2.org_id AND lic.product = 'GOOGLE')`.

Comment: Understood clearly @LukStorms. You could update the answer with this condition if you'd like to.

Comment: @Naveen but if you want the counts per childs, then you should also put `org2.org_id, org2.org_name`  in the GROUP BY and the SELECT